# Azure Pipeline: Update variables according to parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

I have some very simple variables, which I would like to change according to the environment.

I have written the code below in very different ways (including indentation) but none was fruitful. Alternatives I see are

- Use variable groups (trying to avoid to have too many of them)
- Write a bash script which updates the variables (will work but I
  think its not a super neat solution)

```
variables:
  - group : secrets

  - name: hello
    value: world


  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'dev') }}:
    - name: RabbitMQ_replicaCount
      value: 3
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'test') }}:
      RabbitMQ_replicaCount: '1'
```

Any other ideas will be appriciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go by a PS script/Bash script for this task. Why ? The logic part of build where manipulation is needed like setting or overriding var based on branch or env can be done in a better way in script rather than the build yaml itself. Also this part un-necessary elongates the yaml.

**Step 1** : Define a  var in the build pipe with default env name

[image]

and may be another var whose value you want to set based on condition

[image]

**Step 2** : Add a yml file(lets name it `BuildEnv.yml`) in your repo which actually contains your PowerShell/Bash code:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    if($BuildEnv -ne "Test"){
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildEnv]Dev"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RabbitMQ_replicaCount]11"
    }
  displayName: 'Override Build Env'
  # MORE CODE HERE
```

**Step 3**: Plug your yml in the build pipe as a template-

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - master

name: $(date:yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm)_$(rev:.r)

stages:

- stage: Build_Stage
  displayName: Build_Stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    pool:
      name: ABC

    steps:

    - template: ..\BuildEnv.yml

    #REST CODE
```

That's it. You are done.

Reference : Template usage in Azure DevOps build - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops