# Dynamic variable group in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to be able to use a variable group in Azure DevOps Pipeline based upon a generated name.

Like so: (where `dtapName` is a letter like `d` or `t`.)

```yaml
variables:
- group: 'project-${{ dtapName }}'
```

I've seen it work in other pipelines but creating one myself has been a pain.

My current pipeline is as follows:
The variable group "global-d" contains a variable 'dtapName' with value 'd'.
And the variable group "project-t" contains URLs and such specific for our 'develop' landscape.

File "pipeline-infra.yaml":

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - Project/pipelines

stages:
- stage: Develop
  displayName: Develop deployment of Project
  variables:
  - name: environmentName
    value: 'develop-o'
  - group: 'global-o'
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Debug_001'
    environment: ${{ variables.environmentName }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: echo [Testing job]
            - script: echo v.environment = ${{ variables.environmentName }} # Does work
            - script: echo v.dtapName = ${{ variables.dtapName }} #❗Fails, why? It is defined in the variable group 'global-o'
            # script: echo environment = ${{ environmentName }} #❗Failed, why does it work in the template call below?
            # script: echo dtapName = ${{ dtapName }} #❗Failed, why does it work in the template call below?
            - script: echo env ENVIRONMENTNAME = $ENVIRONMENTNAME # Does work
            - script: echo env DTAPNAME = $DTAPNAME  # Does work

  - template: pipeline-infra.extra.yaml
    parameters:
      environment: $(environmentName)
      dtapName: $(dtapName)
```

File "pipeline-infra.extra.yaml"

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environment
  type: string
- name: dtapName
  type: string

jobs:
- deployment: 'Debug_002'
# environment: ${{ parameters.environment }} #❗Fails with: Environment $(environmentName) could not be found.  WHY?
  environment: 'develop-o'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  variables:
  - name: placeholder
    value: 'none'
# - group: 'project-${{ parameters.dtapName }}' #❗Fails with: Variable group 'project-$(dtapName)' could not be found. How to do this?
  strategy: 
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo [ pipeline-infra.extra.yaml ]
        - script: echo Environment = ${{ parameters.environment }} # WORKS
        - script: echo "Environment (v) = ${{ variables.environmentName }}" #❗FAILS, this variable is declare on the stage of this job... why can't it be accessed?
        - script: echo Parameter = ${{ parameters.dtapName }} # WORKS
        - script: echo PARAMETER = $DTAPNAME # WORKS
        - script: echo Variable  = ${{ variables.dtapName }} #❗FAILS, would think this comes available when the problem in the calling stage is fixed
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: VariableListing 2
          inputs:
            targetType: inline
            script: 'env | sort'
```

Can anyone explain me (or point me to a description) why these problems occur?
I've read (most of) [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) and documents linked from here.
It's probably a little thing, but for the past couple of days I'm not seeing it.

Comment: For variable group my guess is you haven't linked the vars to the build pipe may be. Build Pipe > edit > Triggers > Variables > Variable groups > Link variable...
For other issue may be this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189739/azure-pipeline-update-variables-according-to-parameter/70190755#70190755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your main yaml:

1. You `cannot` invoke variables from Variable group with template expression `${{ variables.var }}`. Template variables are processed at compile time, and are replaced before runtime starts. It `cannot` get variable value from Group, it can get value from predefined variable.
2. Template expression should have format as `${{ variables.var }}` not `${{ var }}`.

Please check doc: [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) for the details. I add the comment on your yaml below:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - Project/pipelines

stages:
- stage: Develop
  displayName: Develop deployment of Project
  variables:
  - name: environmentName
    value: 'develop-o'
  - group: 'global-o'
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Debug_001'
    environment: ${{ variables.environmentName }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: echo [Testing job]
            - script: echo v.environment = ${{ variables.environmentName }} # Does work, it use template expression syntax and can get the value as it's predefined variable.
            - script: echo v.dtapName = ${{ variables.dtapName }} #❗Not work, Template variables are processed at compile time, and are replaced before runtime starts, it cannot get the Test Group variable value, should use macro syntax $(dtapName).
            # script: echo environment = ${{ environmentName }} #❗Failed, syntax error, should be ${{ variables.environmentName }} or $(environmentName)
            # script: echo dtapName = ${{ dtapName }} #❗Failed, syntax error, should be $(dtapName)
            - script: echo env ENVIRONMENTNAME = $ENVIRONMENTNAME # Does work, the variable is set as environment value, you can use it with syntax $NAME.
            - script: echo env DTAPNAME = $DTAPNAME  # Does work,the variable is set as environment value, you can use it with syntax $NAME.

  - template: pipeline-infra.extra.yaml
    parameters:
      environment: $(environmentName) # Environment creation happens at compile time, if you pass marco syntax to template, it will cause the error, should use template expreesion ${{ variables.environmentName }}.
      dtapName: $(dtapName)  # not work here, should define it out of variable group, and transfer with parameter expression same as above.
```

For your template yaml:

1. Environment creation happens at compile time, so if you define `$(environmentName)` in main yaml for the template, it cannot get the value, you should use template expression `${{ variables.environmentName }}` in `main` yaml to transfer the value.
2. No variable defined in template, you `cannot` use ${{ variables.var }}, you should use parameters expression `${{ parameters.var }}`.

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  type: string
- name: dtapName
  type: string

jobs:
- deployment: 'Debug_002'
# environment: ${{ parameters.environment }} #❗Fails, should use ${{ variables.environmentName }} in main yaml for template.
  environment: 'develop-o'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  variables:
  - name: placeholder
    value: 'none'
# - group: 'project-${{ parameters.dtapName }}' #❗Fails, same as above, it cannot get the value 
  strategy: 
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo [ pipeline-infra.extra.yaml ]
        - script: echo Environment = ${{ parameters.environment }} # WORKS
        - script: echo "Environment (v) = ${{ variables.environmentName }}" #❗FAILS, should use parameter expression as no variable defined.
        - script: echo Parameter = ${{ parameters.dtapName }} # WORKS
        - script: echo PARAMETER = $DTAPNAME # WORKS
        - script: echo Variable  = ${{ variables.dtapName }} #❗FAILS, same as above.
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: VariableListing 2
          inputs:
            targetType: inline
            script: 'env | sort'
```

Comment: Hi @SvenL, could you please let me know if it's helpful? Let me know if you have any queries, thanks.