# Run Azure DevOps Build Pipeline Multiple Times

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dynamics-crm, power-platform

I have created an Azure DevOps Pipeline to export a solution from development environment and import it in our UAT and other environments. A variable named as $(SolutionName) has also been introduced to specify the name of the solution to be exported and imported. The Pipeline is working fine as per the expected behavior.

However, I have multiple solutions in my development environment and would like to Export all of them and Import in my UAT and other environment's. In order to achieve this, I would like to Run the same pipeline for each solution by changing the variable name.

Could anyone can let me know, How can I do this automatically (May be by adding an iterative job or script to get it done)?

Comment: May be a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189739/azure-pipeline-update-variables-according-to-parameter/70190755#70190755

Comment: Thanks @AatifAkhter It is all about the variable I would like to know the iteration too.